# Speed and efficiency of solenoid train?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, electromagnet

I'm talking about a simple solenoid train as shown in below image that works on the same principal as a homo-polar motor. It consists of an electric cell (AA or AAA type) whose terminals are fitted with neodymium disc magnets. This setup is called a train. When this train is placed inside a copper coil, the train moves. The working principal is explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWuICjRU3t0) YouTube video.

[image]

Now how do I determine the speed and efficiency of a solenoid train?

For determining efficiency, I think I could divide the product of displacement of the train and the Lorentz force by the output power of the battery, neglecting the friction between the train and coil as given in below equation:

μ=  (Power of train) / (Power of battery)  =  (D × IBL) / (I × V)

Where,
μ is the efficiency of the train.
D is the displacement of the train.
I is the current in the coil. Which is the same as the output current from the cell.
B is the magnetic strength of the neodymium magnets.
L is the length of the portion of the coil acting as a solenoid which is equal to the length of the train.
V is the voltage of the cell.

For calculating veleocity of the train can I use Newton's second law of motion:

F = m x (v/t)

From which,

v = (F x t)/m

Where,

v is velocity of train.
F is Lorentz force driving the train.
t is the time taken by the train to displace itself.
m is the mass of the train.

Comment: The magnet polarity is not shown correctly. How will you determine the current? How will the velocity vary over time? Do you have a closed path or does the train just go from on end to the other and then stop? If the path is not continuous, how long is it? Why do you think it is appropriate to neglect friction?

Comment: Friction should not factor into efficiency measurements. But friction is what will set the train's velocity, so you can't neglect that if you are calculating the velocity. Otherwise the train would keep getting faster and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You neglect friction. If you also neglect air resistance, and have an infinitely long, straight coil, and the battery has an infinite charge so it will never run empty, then, I'd guess, the train will reach eventually the speed of light. Eventually meaning after an infinite amount of time.

Comment: Actually the speed is limited by the generated back emf. When the bemf equals the battery voltage, the theoretical max. Speed is reached

Comment: @JG97 Very sharp! You made me think also about commutation. The last winding that is carrying a current will be short-circuited by the rear magnet, so that the magnetic field of that winding will lose its energy in the ohmic resistance in that magnet. Then, at the front, a new winding needs to be energized, which needs the same amount of energy as gets dissipated at the rear winding. This energy loss also limits the max speed. The battery can only energize a certain number of windings per second. At this moment I am not sure if this is the same as your back-emf, I need to think about it.